# Remove external Library with Android Studio? ( not working)

Tags: android

I am trying to remove a support library in android studio, I only want to use one however someone another two got added.( i think maybe they are part of some jars I added? ) I dont know but i cant delete them and they keep re generating. When I click on module settings and the minus sign they just regenerate again. I want only ONE support library yet there are three. can anyone tell me HOW to delete them? I keep getting this error : Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompatIceCreamSandwich.class

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AcWG.png)

Comment: You use Gradle? Can you remove the support library by deleting from gradle dependencies?

Comment: Have you checked your app module's build.gradle file? Are multiple dependencies added there?

Comment: If you use Gradle, please include the app-level `build.gradle` so it can be examined.

Comment: @Eenvincible I have only one support lib ( the one of choice) in my gradle dependencies ...

Comment: And you still have the error? There could be another library using a different version of the library